# pymongo find() vs find()[:]?

Tags: python, pyramid, pymongo

I am using PyMongo, and saw someone recommending use of `find()[:]` instead of `find()`. Am curious as to what the difference is?

Comment: Using `[:]` makes a shallow copy of the list. However, keep in mind that the references to the objects are the same. I don't know if it is relevant for the pymongo module.

Comment: oh.. dumb me.. should have known that. :) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[:]` makes a shallow copy of the list, so the references to the objects are the same. I've looked at the Pymongo documentation, and I don't see any reason to make that copy of the result of `find()`. I think it is even worse, since you have to iterate again over the result set:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('range(100000)[:]', number=1000)
2.056607127195644
>>> timeit('range(100000)', number=1000)
1.1496167131002366
```

Comment: yeah, i just thought it's a different notation, totally forgot about the cloning. thanks.
btw, you should add your old comment to the answer.